# Debug a MS Word Macro Invoked from another app using OLE

Tags: vba, debugging, ole

I have a C++ app that invokes a mail merge in a word macro in a .docm file. The macro works on Windows XP but not on Windows 7. I want to debug the macro first in Windows XP where it works then move to Windows 7 where it doesn't.

I have set a break point in the macro to debug but I'm unable to get the debugger to engage when invoked from my app. I used to do this many years ago (and versions of WORD). Is it still possible to do this, I've exhaustively googled this for the last day and a half and I've come up with nothing.

Comment: Also would be pertinent: What version(s) of Word?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to read and consider my post. The version of Word being used is 2010 on both my XP and Win 7 machines. After I get this running in 2010 then I will adapt to Word 2013. The IDE for the C++ app is Visual Studio 6. The C++ executable runs without problems in Win 7 despite the fact that VS 6 C++ IDE cannot be installed on Win 7. 

Some more details; I have gone into Word's Trust Center Settings and set the 'Enable all macros' radio button, a necessary step in making this work. I have also set 'Trust access to the VBA project object model' with no success.

Comment: In Win 7 after recording the macro and saving it, I had to reopen it and convert it to 2010 as if it were from a prior version of Word to stop it from coming up in compatibility mode which, as I understand it, disables macros.

Comment: In summary, this macro works (via OLE invocation from C++ app) in Word 2010 on an XP machine but not on a Win 7 machine. I would like to engage the VBA macro debugger automatically when the macro starts up, first in the XP environment where things are working, then in the Win 7 environment to figure out what's wrong. I have confirmed that I have set break points in the same instance of the macro that the C++ app invokes and I haven't been able to get the VBA macro debugger to engage from either OS.

Answer (score 0):

If your c++ app uses CoCreateInstance to load Word as a local server then the breakpoint you set in the Word VBA IDE macro will not be triggered because CoCreateInstance is starting a new process for Word.

Open only I instance of word, set your breakpoint in the macro and then use GetActiveObject (instead of CoCreateInstance) in your c++ app to get a reference to the Word Local Server. That should cause your breakpoint to trigger.

For example I created a Word macro called TestMacro that just showed a message box. I put a break point on MsgBox "..." in my macro. I then called my macro from a .vbs script:

```
dim wdApp
set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
'set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

wdApp.Run "TestMacro"
```

When I used GetObject, my breakpoint triggered. When I used CreateObject my breakpoint did not trigger.

Comment: My app that invokes Word is written in C++ not VBS. I can't really tell if its equivalnt to the VBS above. It's longer that this comment field so I'm going to break it into 2 pieces. here is the first part:

Comment: WordApplication glWordAppVer8Obj;

WordBasic glWordBasicObj;

::CLSIDFromProgID(L"Word.Application", &clsid);

glWordAppVer8Obj.ReleaseDispatch();

glWordBasicObj.ReleaseDispatch();

glWordAppVer8Obj.CreateDispatch("Word.Application", &glWordOLEException)
glWordBasicObj.AttachDispatch(glWordAppVer8Obj.GetWordBasic());

glWordAppVer8Obj.SetVisible(TRUE);

glWordAppVer8Obj.SetWindowState(2);

Comment: glWordBasicObj.FileNew(COleVariant(LPCTSTR( "I:\TemplateDiy\REPORT.docm")), COleVariant((short) 0));
glWordBasicObj.ViewNormal();
glWordBasicObj.SetDocumentVar("LetterFile", "I:\TemplateDir\LetterTemplate.docx");
glWordBasicObj.SetDocumentVar("TempFileName", "C:\TempDir\MyMergeData.txt");
glWordBasicObj.ToolsMacro(COleVariant("MyMacroName"),
   COleVariant((short) TRUE), 
   COleVariant((short) FALSE),
   COleVariant((short) 3),
   COleVariant((short) FALSE), 
   COleVariant((short) FALSE),
   COleVariant(""),
   COleVariant(""),
   COleVariant((short) FALSE));

Comment: If CreateDispatch internally calls CoCreateInstance, I think you can modify your c++ code to call GetActiveObject. Instead of calling `glWordAppVer8Obj.CreateDispatch("Word.Application", &glWordOLEException)` call `IUnknown * pUnk; IDispatch * pdispWdApp; HRESULT hr = GetActiveObject(clsid, NULL, &pUnk); hr = pUnk->QueryInterface(IID_IDispatch, &pdispWdApp); glWordAppVer8Obj.AttachDispatch(pdispWdApp);`

Comment: On the call     hr = pUnk->QueryInterface(IID_IDispatch, &pdispWdApp);     I get a complie error; "error C2664: 'long __stdcall IUnknown::QueryInterface(const struct _GUID &,void ** )' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'struct IDispatch ** ' to 'void ** '
        Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast".   A C style cast (void**) compiles but fails.  I don't dabble in COM very often and if you have advice on this call to QueryInterface I'd be appreciative.

Comment: When you say the call to QueryInterface on the IUnknown * fails do you mean the call returns an error code? If so, what is the error code? Or do you mean there is an access violation due to pUnk being NULL because the call to GetActiveObject failed? If that is the case, what is the error that GetActiveObject returns?

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood; if I use a "C style cast" I get a memory error in QueryInterface. It never returns pdispWdApp and the error produced specifically is **Unhandled exception in myApp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access Violation**

Comment: That sounds like pUnk is NULL which means that the call to GetActiveObject failed. I can think of two reasons why GetActiveObject would fail. 1) You don't have Word open when your c++ app called GetActiveObject. 2) The thread that called GetActiveObject did not previously call OleInitialize(NULL) or CoInitialize(NULL). What is the return value of your call to GetActiveObject()?